# Huge performance difference when a function parameter changed types from int to unsigned

Tags: c++, performance, benchmarking

I've got a function that's supposed to sum all the natural numbers divisible by 3 and 5. I didn't want to settle for the most obvious solution and tried to come up with something that performs better than just a single for loop with an if statement.

I've come up with the function below. At first there was just one param, `limit`, but then I wanted to try and distribute the computation to multiple threads, so I've introduced a second default param, `lowerLimit`. If I run and benchmark the following code with limit set to 99999999999999 (lowerLimit left with default value), the program takes about 3.5 seconds. **However**, when I changed the type from int to unsigned, the code took so much time to run, that I've decided to stop it and not wait for the output. Where does the difference come from?

**TLDR:** Why does the following code take way more time to run when the type of lowerLimit changes from int to unsigned?

```
unsigned long sumNaturalNumbersDivisibleBy3And5UpToNumber(unsigned long limit, int lowerLimit = 0)
{
    unsigned long sum = 0;
    for (auto threes = lowerLimit + 3; threes <= limit; threes += 3)
    {
        sum += threes;
    }
    for (auto fives = lowerLimit + 5; fives <= limit; fives += 5)
    {
        sum += fives;
    }
    for (auto fifteens = lowerLimit + 15; fifteens <= limit; fifteens += 15)
    {
        sum -= fifteens;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

UPDATE:
As PaulMcKenzie suggested, there is probably an overflow bug when assigning values to threes, fives and fifteens. I'm still not sure why that would cause a performance gap though.

Comment: Which compiler and compilation options are you using?

Comment: Considering that on almost all systems you will ever work with will have `int` as a 32-bit signed integer, a value such as `99999999999999` will be way out of bounds. I assume that `unsigned long` is a 64-bit type on your system.

Comment: *Where does the difference come from?* -- Maybe because your program has an overflow bug?

Comment: You should have got a warning with that large int-literal.

Comment: *I didn't want to settle for the most obvious solution and tried to come up with something that performs better than just a single for loop with an if statement.* -- Note that compiler optimizers are amazing things in this day and age. There is a good chance all of those manipulations with the code you're doing won't make any difference in speed.

Comment: Off-topic: What will you do if lowerLimit is *not* a multiple of 15???

Comment: Oh, you should have written 3 **or** 5; by 3 **and** 5 most people here probably would understand only those numbers that can be deviced by *both* 3 *and* 5 (i. e. multiples of 15)...

Comment: "Which compiler and compilation options are you using?" - g++ and clang++. Whether I did -g0, -g1, -g or -g3 didn't make much difference.
"99999999999999 will be way out of bound" - that value goes as unsigned long.
"What will you do if lowerLimit is not a multiple of 15" - nothing, I'm just playing around, let's say that a limitation to the parameter.
"Oh, you should have written 3 or 5; by 3 and 5" - yeah, that'd have been better :)

Comment: @user6646922 Try compiling with `-O3` instead. You should also [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58226118/edit) your question and replace "_3 and 5_" with "_3 or 5_".

Comment: It's not just a performance gap. The unsigned version is probably an infinite loop. If you give a limit, which is larger than the maximum value of `unsigned int`, then the loop never ends. On the other hand, the `int` version has UB, as signed overflow is undefined.

Comment: "_I'm still not sure why that would cause a performance gap though_" - Does your version using a signed `long` ever finish?

Comment: Probably not, there was no result after half an hour. I guess the infinite loop hypothesis must be right then

Comment: The sum of "all the natural numbers divisible by 3 or 5" is not a number anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If your version with `int lowerLimit` actually finishes, it's because it overflows and what happens then is undefined behaviour (for signed integers). It could just as well wrap around at `2^31-1` to `-2^31` and continue the loop forever - or do something completely different (look up "*nasal demons*").

If you try this inside your `int lowerLimit` version:

```
auto threes = lowerLimit + 3;
for(; threes <= limit; threes += 3) {
    sum += threes;
}
std::cout << threes << " " << limit << "\n";
```

One possible output if you happen to compile with the `g++` option `-fsanitize=undefined`:

> `runtime error: signed integer overflow: 2147483646 + 3 cannot be represented in type 'int'`
>   `-2147483647 99999999999999`

It has actually finished the loop with `threes` being a negative number which is of course lesser than `limit`. It looks impossible, but the compiler is free to do whatever it wants - the behaviour is undefined. This is a *nasal demon* of sorts.

If *I* compile the same thing without `-fsanitize=undefined` - it'll run forever. It's still undefined behaviour so that might not happen for you.

If you change to `unsigned int`, what happens at `2^32-1` is actually well defined. For a 32 bit `unsigned int` the result of `2^32-1 + 1 == 0`.

Such a program *must* run forever (since `threes` can never reach `99999999999999`) as long as it has some side-effects. An endless loop without side-effects also has Undefined Behaviour - so even though every individual operation in the function has defined behaviour, an implementation capable of realizing that the loop is infinite and doesn't have side-effects, could make anything happen.

The solution is to use the same type for `threes`, `fives` and `fifteens` as `limit` - but with a `limit` set to `99999999999999`, be prepared to wait for a really really long time.

Comment: An infinite loop without side effects is also UB (http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.progress#1) so it is not quite true that in the unsigned situation a program _must_ run forever. It may or may not.

Comment: @JeffGarrett It seems I forgot to ack that. Ack! :-)

Answer (score 1):

> I've got a function that's supposed to sum all the natural numbers divisible by 3 and 5. I didn't want to settle for the most obvious solution and tried to come up with something that performs better than just a single for loop with an if statement.

This isn't even close to fast.

"Fast" would look something like this:

```
int thingy1[] = 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6;

int thingy2[] = 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3+5, 3+5+6, 3+5+6, 3+5+6, 3+5+6+9, 3+5+6+9+10, 3+5+6+9+10, 3+5+6+9+10+12, 3+5+6+9+10+12, 3+5+6+9+10+12;

unsigned long getSumOfNaturalNumbersDivisibleBy3Or5UpToNumber(unsigned long limit) {
    unsigned long sum = 0;
    unsigned long i;

    for(i = 0; i < limit/15; i++) {
        sum += i*15*7 + 3+5+6+9+10+12+15;
    }
    return sum + (limit/15) * thingy1[limit % 15] * 15 + thingy2[limit % 15];
}


unsigned long getCountOfNaturalNumbersDivisibleBy3Or5UpToNumber(unsigned long limit) {
    return (limit / 15) * 7 + thingy1[limit % 15];
}
```

Comment: The OP wants *sum* of numbers, not *count*.  But yes, with Gauss's `n*(n+1)/2` formula and the repeating pattern, a closed-form formula is likely possible.

Comment: @PeterCordes: D'oh - you're right. Fixed maybe (might be an "off by one" bug in there now)

Comment: I think you need to adjust your text.  The OP's code is *much* better than `if(i%3 == 0) sum+=i;`.  Your code still has a loop.  Yours does significantly fewer iterations, but the OP avoided division.  It's not as fast as it could be, but it's closer to "fast" than it is to the most naive implementation.  You too could have avoided division for your loop bound by doing `i+=15` and `i<limit`.  Although I guess you still need a mod15 at the end.

Comment: @PeterCordes: One of the benefits of using higher level languages (instead of something like assembly language) is that you can write readable/maintainable code (and let the compiler figure out that it can/should convert it into something less readable, like "`for(i = 60; i < limit*7 + 60; i += 105) sum += i;`", where its not obvious where all the magic numbers came from).